# CSS font-weight options

Tags: css

I don't get the values 100 to 900 in CSS font-weight. I see 100 to 500 like regular size and 600 to 900 like bold. Only two font weights. Tried h1, font-size:60px, etc. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rich said, depends on the font, but it's a really good question because it does impact how the font renders, especially @font-face fonts. If you get the number wrong, or just use 'bold' instead of the correct number, it can render the font as jaggy.

This is a good article on that: http://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/

Sorry not to be able to answer your question - I did search and can't find any sites listing available font-weights per font. Would be a handy resource! For now you could just try the various font selling sites like [Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/), [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect) etc, or search for the font you're using and go to one of the sites where it's sold; hopefully that site will give its available font-weight sizes.

Comment: This is not entirely true: "If you get the number wrong, or just use 'bold' instead of the number" `bold` is a keyword that means exactly the same as `700`. (Similarly, `normal` is the same as `400`.) If there's a difference, that would be a bug in the browser.

Comment: Good to know Mr Lister, I didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the font you are using. Some fonts don't have as many weights as others. Helvetica Neue is a good one to test with if you have it - it has quite a few weights.