# Delay loading google font types

Tags: css, fonts

As for [CSS font-weight options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044574/css-font-weight-options) I am trying the ubuntu font.

Link to href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:500,300,700,400italic,400'

All body font-weights are 400 (normal) but title is h2 and font-weight=300
All content loads quickly but the title, it has a small delay I don't like.
I'm not sure how it works, I guess ubuntu-400 is in FF font list but it has to get ubuntu-300 from google server.

If this is true or not, is it correct and useful to download ttf sources and load them from my own server?

Comment: Yeah, fetching a font from a local server is always going to be faster than getting it from Google.

Comment: Loading fonts from my server does not fix this problem. I get it only in FF. Safari and Chrome load all text quickly and at the same time.
This FF issues happens only with font-weight 300 and 500, not with 400(normal) nor 700(bold)

Comment: Shrug, sounds like a Firefox problem, then.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a FF problem, there's nothing you can do about it before it's fixed. A good workaround solution is to use a JS preloader. This way your page appears nice and tight only when fully loaded. [PreLoadMe](http://niklausgerber.com/blog/preloadme-a-lightweight-jquery-website-preloader/) is unobstrusive and does the job.