# How can I find web-fonts with full range of font-weights?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I seek a web font with the full range of font-weights (ie. 100, 200, 300... 900).

All the fonts I have tried seem to support just two font-weights: normal and bold.  If I try the numerical values I get the normal font-weight for 100-500, and the bold font-weight for 600-900.

More info on font-weights is given on the [Mozilla documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

I am aware of [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts), but I see no way to limit results to the fonts I'm interested in.

If anyone can tell me of even one font that has more than two font-weights, that would be helpful.

I tried Helvetica Neue, as recommended in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044574/css-font-weight-options), but I saw only two font-weights.

My browser is Firefox 26.

Comment: *no way to limit results to the fonts I'm interested in* - What do you see on the left hand side of your screen when you visit Google Fonts?

Comment: I see a slider for thickness, slant, and width.  I want fonts supporting a range of thicknesses.

Comment: There are tons of fonts with the whole range of weights—Open Sans, for example, off the top of my head. But there are also lots of font services that include all font weights, such as Typekit etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around more with the Google Fonts site, I found the Sorting option at the top, which allows sorting by 'Number of styles'.  There are many fonts that support a range of font-weights.  The first returned was [Exo](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Exo).

I couldn't get the fonts with numerical font-weight working locally until I figured out that @font-face CSS rules were necessary.  Here is the minimal code required to demonstrate the full range of font-weights for the Exo font.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Exo Font Weights Demo</title>
  <style>
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 100; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/LOvrl2pqswCkT8i3Cr0n-A.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 200; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/6QiS59P8BsX03DD46j0MBA.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/4KZbxe9r2TXLhWnvIEYFtg.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/ciAJ5J-gAMQ5PmKP3W3-DQ.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/P68xbqSRbv2P2Y1Gn89_Sw.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/81Bt2ny37U7oEhl3JhWo7g.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/XImhdIFxStwHS9PAgE4VpA.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 800; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/8F32bA5gdXrOnEJkKVwXsA.woff) format('woff');}
@font-face {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 900; src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/exo/v2/vRBeganESUK4UFluFjuHcQ.woff) format('woff');}

.Exo-normal-100 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 100;}
.Exo-normal-200 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 200;}
.Exo-normal-300 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 300;}
.Exo-normal-400 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;}
.Exo-normal-500 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500;}
.Exo-normal-600 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600;}
.Exo-normal-700 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700;}
.Exo-normal-800 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 800;}
.Exo-normal-900 {font-family: 'Exo'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 900;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="Exo-normal-100">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-200">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-300">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-400">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-500">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-600">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-700">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-800">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
  <p class="Exo-normal-900">Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for the evil Queen</p>
 </body>
</html>
```